# How to extract lines from probability map? (Python,OpenCV)

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I trained a CNN to detect text lines and now I have a probability map for a test image, what is an efficient way to extract bounding boxes of text lines from that?

Here is the probability map:
[image]

Comment: You need to threshold your probability map.

Comment: Thanks but this is too simple method and so the results with these method are inaccurate.